# How can write a long text as cell content of a table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

I have a problem with creating the following table:

[image]

I wrote this code which creates the following table instead of the one above.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| p{3cm}| p{3.5cm} |>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}p{2cm}|>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}p{2cm}| p{2cm}| p{2cm} | }
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Collection} & \multirow{2}{*}\Longstack{Number of relevant \newline documents based on \newline the relevance judgement \newline qrel file } & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Number of relevant \newline documents retrieved \newline (context window size of 5)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Number of relevant \newline documents retrieved \newline (context window size of 10)} \\
\cline{3-6}
{} & {} & {Negative\newline Sampling} & {Hierarchical \newline Softmax} & {Negative\newline Sampling} & {Hierarchical \newline Softmax}\\
\hline
Robust04 & 17,412 & 13,178 & 13,129 & 12,647 & 12,651 \\
\hline
ClueWeb09-B-1m & 212 & 156 & 130 & 157 & 148  \\
\hline
ClueWeb09-B-2m & 1,050 & 990 & 989 & 998 & 984 \\
\hline
ClueWeb09-B-5m & 1,666 & 1,459 & 1,458 & 1,471 & 1,436  \\
\hline
Pooled baseline & 6,390 & 6,196 & 6,085 & 6,024 & 5,964 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Impact of sampling strategies on retrieval effectiveness ($k_3$ and $D500$).} \label{tab:t7}
\end{center}
```

[image]

How can I fixed the problem?

Comment: Welcome! Please make your code compilable so people can reproduce the problem you show. `\multicolumn{2}{c|}` makes a single-line cell, centred. You need a multi-line cell here with `p` or `m` or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would focus of the design effort for this table on (a) aligning the numbers on their respective decimal markers, (b) centering the contents of the five data columns, (c) giving the table a more open look by omitting all vertical lines and most horizontal lines, and (d) giving the header material a more appealing visual structure. I suggest using a `tabularx` environment, as it provides a cell type (`X`) that allows automatic line wrapping -- no need to insert line breaks manually. The following table attempts to incorporate these goals.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\hyphenation{docu-ments}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\sisetup{table-format=5.0,
         group-minimum-digits=4,
         group-separator={,}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{5}{S} @{}}
\toprule
Collection 
& \multicolumn{1}{>{\hsize=1.6\hsize}C}{%
   Number of relevant documents based on the relevance judgement qrel file}
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr1.7\hsize+2\tabcolsep\relax}C}{%
   Number of relevant documents retrieved (context window size of 5)} 
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr1.7\hsize+2\tabcolsep\relax}C}{%
   Number of relevant documents retrieved (context window size of~10} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){5-6}
& % ( 1.6+4*0.85=5, i.e., the number of columns of type "C")
& \multicolumn{1}{>{\hsize=0.85\hsize}C}{Negative Sampling} 
& \multicolumn{1}{>{\hsize=0.85\hsize}C}{Hierarchical Softmax}
& \multicolumn{1}{>{\hsize=0.85\hsize}C}{Negative Sampling} 
& \multicolumn{1}{>{\hsize=0.85\hsize}C@{}}{Hierarchical Softmax}\\
\midrule
Robust04        & 17412 & 13178 & 13129 & 12647 & 12651 \\

ClueWeb09-B-1m  & 212  &  156 &  130 &  157 &  148 \\

ClueWeb09-B-2m  & 1050 &  990 &  989 &  998 &  984 \\

ClueWeb09-B-5m  & 1666 & 1459 & 1458 & 1471 & 1436 \\

Pooled baseline & 6390 & 6196 & 6085 & 6024 & 5964 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Impact of sampling strategies on retrieval effectiveness 
   ($k_3$ and $D500$).} 
\label{tab:t7}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```